# How to authorize a specific client daemon from a different AAD tenant?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, f#, azure-active-directory, jwt

In my server-to-server scenario, I have an ASP.NET Core service in (Azure Active Directory) Tenant A (which I control), and I want to allow a specific (daemon) client app registration in Tenant B (which I do not control) to access my service.

I've found some examples of doing multi-tenant authorization via Role-Based Access Control but I don't want to use roles because I don't understand the security implications of allowing admins in Tenant B to decide who gets the proper "role" to talk to my app. Instead I want to decide myself, and an access control list seems like a good way to do this.

In theory I think I can use JWT Bearer Tokens issued by B, and consume them in A, but I haven't been able to get this working: depending on what I try, authentication fails on the server with 401s like

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer '(null)' is invalid"
```

and

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"
```

even though my bearer token seems to validate fine in jwt.io ("Signature verified", "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/4510468d-3790-4a1a-8209-84281b2d1596/").

My code is in a [git repo](https://github.com/MaxWilson/MultiTenantTest/tree/main/app) and here is my startup:

```
type Startup(configuration: IConfiguration) =
    member _.Configuration = configuration

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-web-api for more
    member _.ConfigureServices(services: IServiceCollection) =
        services
            .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(fun o ->

                configuration.Bind(o)
                o.TokenValidationParameters <- new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters(ValidateAudience=true)
                )
            .Services.AddControllers() |> ignore

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    member _.Configure(app: IApplicationBuilder, env: IWebHostEnvironment) =
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) then
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() |> ignore
        app.UseHttpsRedirection()
           .UseRouting()
           .UseAuthentication()
           .UseAuthorization()
           .UseEndpoints(fun endpoints ->
                endpoints.MapControllers() |> ignore
            ) |> ignore
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "wilsonsoft.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "88ac0449-3fae-4113-a1ba-fb4f2d041702",
    "TenantId": "c4568757-6752-4ed0-a24a-b5ab2df02011"
  }
}
```

A typical request:

```
GET https://localhost:44336/weatherforecast/who HTTP/1.1
Authorization: bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyIsImtpZCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyJ9.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.DwpWaOqoZgNoDka6-0FYQr1ivllL2taXdqtat_65x_kuT6r3uiknhL19Fu6dFmJ7UCgjc3-JZh5Bee0uZvVHbwCjZKHsUNrDEANnDkK4hGFzSKyU3NL7X9iRdPeBl3-GUSRGbPeozHTF93epSEhDyY3PkS1ICEfdAG7yi8cerBzmuy-lsUWs90sWlrWVYjDRtFWzwlovNgS6mPkx2cKlsC34WK6QXafJYqPcA5XW1EqZGyA5S0qvQS0VaheABEfkTIC8pEijieImWKIqFefd2G7blBB1Qdng4NAPcHOhmnRSiClCrwXS_5hOYsUXFS4xVAMPIZx9peWXMlk6XyQzNg
Host: localhost:44336
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 29 Mar 2021 16:06:48 GMT

0
```

Can anyone advise on what this error message is trying to tell me and/or if there's a better way to accomplish my goal of authorizing a specific client in a different tenant, in ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

The answer: in multi-tenant scenarios, you must authenticate against the "common" endpoint AND ALSO use a custom TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator that transforms the "iss" claim before checking it. That will allow you to authenticate with the jwt token. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-web-api for more details.

Then, authorization is a straightforward matter of checking the app id claim.

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.

member _.ConfigureServices(services: IServiceCollection) =
    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII <- true
    services
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(fun jwtOptions ->
            jwtOptions.TokenValidationParameters <-
                new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters(
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true
                    )
            jwtOptions.Authority <- "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
            jwtOptions.Audience <- "https://wilsonsoft.onmicrosoft.com/HelloWeather"
            jwtOptions.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator <-
                fun issuer jwt tokenValidationParams ->
                    // In order to support multi-tenant auth, replace {tenantid} placeholder with actual tenantId,
                    // e.g. "https://sts.windows.net/{tenantid}/" becomes "https://sts.windows.net/{c4568757-6752-4ed0-a24a-b5ab2df02011}/"
                    // See https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/12/24/multitenant-azure-ad-issuer-validation-in-asp-net-core/ for more
                    let validatedIssuer =
                        match jwt with
                        | :? JwtSecurityToken as jwt ->
                            match jwt.Payload.TryGetValue("tid") with
                            | true, (:? string as tenantId) ->
                                let validIssuers =
                                    (Seq.append tokenValidationParams.ValidIssuers [tokenValidationParams.ValidIssuer])
                                    |> Seq.filter (System.String.IsNullOrEmpty >> not)
                                    |> Seq.map (fun i -> i.Replace("{tenantid}", tenantId))
                                validIssuers |> Seq.tryFind (fun i -> i = issuer)
                            | _ -> None
                        | _ -> None
                    match validatedIssuer with
                    | Some i -> i
                    | None ->
                        $"IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: '{issuer}'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: '{tokenValidationParams.ValidIssuer}' or validationParameters.ValidIssuers: '{tokenValidationParams.ValidIssuers}'."
                        |> SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException
                        |> raise
            )
        .Services.AddAuthorization(fun authzOptions ->
            // only allow specific appIds (from trusted issuers) access to this app
            authzOptions.AddPolicy(
                "ACL",
                (fun policy ->
                    policy.RequireAssertion(fun ctx ->
                        ctx.User.HasClaim(fun claim ->
                            claim.Type = "appid" && claim.Value = "083d3ba2-ed4e-4e11-b7ef-d8cc46ffe346")
                        )
                    |> ignore
                ))
            )
        .AddControllers() |> ignore
```

[Fixed version](https://github.com/MaxWilson/MultiTenantTest).